# Why does declarative coding lend it self to parallel computing

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, declarative

In [Mostly Adequate Guide](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch6.html#declarative-coding) drboolean posits that "declarative coding lends itself to parallel computing". Take the following example:

```
// imperative
var authenticate = function(form) {
  var user = toUser(form);
  return logIn(user);
};

// declarative
var authenticate = compose(logIn, toUser);
```

I thought the order is preserved in compose(right to left). So what additional power does declarative coding provide for the purpose of parallel computing?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you about the order, it must be preserved at least in the `authenticate` example.

Regarding the features that might make declarative a more parallel-friendly paradigm, it's all about modularity. You can see it better in the first example (the cars one):

```
// imperative
var makes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  makes.push(cars[i].make);
}

// declarative
var makes = cars.map(function(car) { return car.make; });
```

Here, the declarative version is written with a separate function that could be run asynchronously while in the imperative version, you just have a some code mixed with the rest of your code.

The declarative design just makes it easier to get some pieces wrapped in different processes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the guide is kind of misleading at this point, by using `compose` as an example right before this statement.

In the case of `compose`, the declarative style won't allow for parallel computing, because even while using `compose`, `toUser` will still have to be executed before `logIn`, since it depends on it's output!

I think the `map` example is better for illustrating this. While you'll have to execute the for loop step-by-step, since you don't really know what the next step will look like, if you haven't done the previous one, you can't really do all steps at once. When you're using `map` on the other hand, you give it a pure function which is executed on each item of the collection. The function is an atomic action and it's execution does not depend on the execution of the function before nor after it. Therefore you could execute them all at once in parallel.

But an important addition to this, which is also mentioned in the guide, but was cut out of your quotation of it, is that the function has to be pure (meaning that they won't change the data structure they are "operating on", but instead return a new one). A good example for this would be:

```
// impure
var impureSquared = function (list) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = list[i] * list[i];
  }
}

// pure
var pureSquared = function (list) {
  return list.map(function (item) {
     return item * item;
  }
}
```

If you would run the impure function on the same data structure in two threads in parallel, you probably wouldn't get the result you expect, since the data structure is changed twice, by this function in each thread. If you would do the same with the pure function on the other hand, both threads would get the expected result without interfering with each other.

I think the concept of pure functions doing atomic actions is actually more important to parallel execution than declarative programming. You just usually happen to do just that, while coding in a declarative style.

All that being said, I should add, that javascript generally is a single-threaded language, so it's not really the language to talk about, when you talk about parallel computing ;)

Comment: So do you imply that implementation of map in JavaScript involves parallel execution for all the elements in the iterable, which, however, is not called parallel computing?

Comment: No! I'm sorry, if this was confusing, I'll try to clear things up a bit.
First of all, you got to know, that Javascript generally is a single-threaded language (with a few exception in specific cases..). Therefore, it won't ever truly run anything in parallel, no matter what, or how you code it.

Comment: None the less, while the concepts I described apply to any language, just because you use `map`, it does NOT imply, that you also execute it in parallel! Also using a "traditional" for-loop, does not necessarily mean, that you can't run things in parallel. It just is a lot easier to go ahead and make your code run in parallel, if you apply these principles, because you do not have to take as many additional things into consideration, when suddenly going parallel. It basically just scales better in theory, whether you scale it or not.

Comment: I'm sorry if this got you confused, but I just used javascript, because it is the language you submitted you question in. If you want to have a look at somethings like this in a language, where you actually can go parallel, have look at [parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) in Java.